# React page that fetch data from a php query and then send it to another php page

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I'm new in `React` and I want to code a page (in `React`) that shows data from an external query in `PHP` and then, after the user update that data, axios send it to another `PHP`page. I can do a page that shows only the fetched data and one that sends data but not one that do everything.

Here's my code:

**React Page:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ClientUpdate extends Component 
{
    state = {
      client: []
    }
    
    componentDidMount() 
    {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8888/select_client.php'
      axios.get(url).then(response =>
        this.setState({ client: response.data }));
    }
       
    handleInputChange = (event) => 
    {
      this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    };
      
    handleSubmit = (event) => 
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8888/update_client.php", formData)
        .then((response) => 
        {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => 
        {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
      
    render() 
    {
      return (
                <div className="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
                   {this.state.cliente.map((rs, index) => (
                    <form key={index} className="form-group" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <h1 className="mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center">UPDATE</h1>
                            <input type="hidden" className="form-control" name="id_cliente" id="id_cliente" value={rs.Id_cliente} />
                            <div>
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder={rs.Username} autoComplete="on" value={rs.Username} onChange={this.handleInputChange/ />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email"  className="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder={rs.Email} autoComplete="on" value={rs.Email} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" id="password" autoComplete="off" value={rs.Password} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                            </div>

                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-100 mt-3">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    ))}
                </div>
        );
     }
}
      
export default ClientUpdate;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Surely you want to pull the new data back from PHP and display it in your react app? So you should have a pHP script which provides the data in, for example, JSON format, then you can make a call to that script with axios, get the response data and use it to populate a template in your react code

Comment: I have two PHP scripts, one for send data and one for receive data and they work. The only thing that doesn't work (and I don't know how to implement it) is this react script.

Comment: I don't React myself really, but I would be amazed if you can't [look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+get+data+from+server+and+display+it) to find out how to start doing your task - fetching data from the server (i.e. PHP script in your case) and displaying is going to be a pretty common requirement